# why does shell_exec not work/ not output for certain commands?

Tags: php, linux, shell-exec

```
 echo shell_exec("ps auxwww");
 echo shell_exec("cut -d. -f1 /proc/uptime");
 echo shell_exec("date");
```

gives output;

```
 echo shell_exec("ifconfig eth0");
 echo shell_exec("top -n 1");
```

does not give output

all of these commands work fine when i log in as root through putty and exc them. I read some questions here of some similar issues, one said adding "2>&1" to the end of the command will fix it. That didn't do anything in my case. Also tried using just exec() instead of shell_exce(). Anyone know what's going on? / what I'm doing wrong?

thank you for your time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11072084/2401804  <--here's your answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [shell\_exec() and exec() not working in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071995/shell-exec-and-exec-not-working-in-php)

Comment: please confirm that the other question fixes your problem, so that this one can be closed as duplicate. the fact that ``ifconfig`` usually lives in ``*/sbin`` seems to make this legit

Comment: I have been looking at that question, I somewhat understand why it doesnt work, but I dont understand the answer, so i cant say whether or not it "fixes my problem"

Comment: my ifconfig is in "/sbin/" so i tried putting 
    shell_exec("cd /sbin/");
and chdir("/sbin/");
before the  shell_exec("ifconfig eth0"); but that didnt help

Comment: You are not in a terminal. Changes in shell environment do not persist between `shell_exec()` calls. And `chdir()` changes the **PHP** working directory.

Comment: you’d need ``shell_exec("/sbin/ifconfig eth0")``, but all that won’t help if (a) ``ifconfig`` is not in ``/sbin`` or (b) if ``/sbin`` is prohibited by php config.

Comment: actually  shell_exec("/sbin/ifconfig eth0") works

Comment: so where do i give the credit to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the commands that generate output through PHP have this in common:

- Do not require root privileges
- They just append stuff to standard output

Common issues include:

- The program execution is failing and you never know because `shell_excec()` has really poor error checking features (though you could, at least, test its return value for `null`)
- The command sends output to an interactive terminal.

And a program execution can fail for exactly the same reasons as in a regular shell:

- Lack of privileges
- Wrong or missing environment variables
- Wrong or missing parameters and/or input data
- Etc., etc., etc.

In your case:

- `ifconfig` is normally at `/sbin/ifconfig`; non-root users do not have `/sbin` in their paths
- `top` expects to update random bytes in a TTY window

My advice is to troubleshoot with a function that provides more information such as [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) but please make sure you actually read such info. It's also helpful to read `stderr`—you can redirect it somewhere else (a file or `stdout`) or [use a function that can read it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) directly.

Comment: ``ifconfig`` certainly does neither need root nor an interactive terminal.

Comment: @JonasWielicki - [Seems so](http://serverfault.com/questions/480812/privileges-for-ifconfig). I'm wondering if it just fails because it isn't in the path.

Comment: you may want to edit that into your answer, as you figured this out before me and the OP wants to give credit. This would make your answer complete.